# MySQL string selecting commands

Tags: mysql, sql, string, function

How can I select a row specific by string values

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=
   -- then some function to test what string it starts with
```

Its a bit hard to explain so i will explain an example with JavaScript

```js
if(mystring.indexOf('targetstring') != -1){
// if that variable contains this string

}

if(mystring.indexOf('targetstring') == 0){
// if that variable starts with this string

}
```

So all in all, I want to select rows, when their name(a string column) starts with or contains a specific string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) and the wildcard `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'john%'; /* name starts with john*/ 

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%john%'; /* name contains john*/
```

Comment: I was basically going to say just that and add this: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name like "%string%"
```

Comment: This selects more than it should. The `%` should be at the end only